# elasticsearch aggregation - why is a match all query not returning keys that a more specific query is?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am doing some aggregations. But the results are not at all what I expect, it seems that they are not aggregating over all the documents matching my query in the index, in which case - what good is it?

As an example, First I do this query:

```
{"index":"datalayer","type":"analysis2","body":{"query":{
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "objects" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "action"
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

and the result is 500 hits with aggregations as follows:

```
"aggregations": {
    "objects": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "thing",
                "doc_count": 278
            },
            {
                "key": "hover",
                "doc_count": 273
            },
            {
                "key": "embedded",
                "doc_count": 57
            },
            {
                "key": "view",
                "doc_count": 50
            },
            {
                "key": "widgets",
                "doc_count": 49
            },
            {
                "key": "hovered",
                "doc_count": 20
            },
            {
                "key": "widgetembed",
                "doc_count": 20
            },
            {
                "key": "products",
                "doc_count": 19
            },
            {
                "key": "create",
                "doc_count": 15
            },
            {
                "key": "image",
                "doc_count": 13
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

that's all well and good but I know I have some where the key should be activation. 
So if I then do the query

```
{"index":"datalayer","type":"analysis2","body":{"query":{
        "bool": {
        "must" : [
            {"match": {"object": "Widget"}}
        ]
    }},
    "aggs" : {
        "objects" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "action"
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

then the result is 45 hits with aggregations

```
"aggregations": {
        "objects": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "widgets",
                    "doc_count": 41
                },
                {
                    "key": "embedded",
                    "doc_count": 40
                },
                {
                    "key": "view",
                    "doc_count": 32
                },
                {
                    "key": "activation",
                    "doc_count": 9
                },
                {
                    "key": "image",
                    "doc_count": 4
                },
                {
                    "key": "create",
                    "doc_count": 3
                },
                {
                    "key": "mapping",
                    "doc_count": 3
                },
                {
                    "key": "widget",
                    "doc_count": 3
                },
                {
                    "key": "adding",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "edit",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

as can be seen in these aggregations I have a some keys that are not in my first aggregation of actions matching all documents. Why is that? And what do I have to do to get a bucket with all documents actions in it.

I don't think it can just be that I need to do pagination or something because I have also tried to do

```
{"index":"datalayer","type":"analysis2","body":{"from":0,"size":500,"query":{
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "objects" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "action"
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

with the exact same aggregation result of

```
"aggregations": {
    "objects": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "thing",
                "doc_count": 278
            },
            {
                "key": "hover",
                "doc_count": 273
            },
            {
                "key": "embedded",
                "doc_count": 57
            },
            {
                "key": "view",
                "doc_count": 50
            },
            {
                "key": "widgets",
                "doc_count": 49
            },
            {
                "key": "hovered",
                "doc_count": 20
            },
            {
                "key": "widgetembed",
                "doc_count": 20
            },
            {
                "key": "products",
                "doc_count": 19
            },
            {
                "key": "create",
                "doc_count": 15
            },
            {
                "key": "image",
                "doc_count": 13
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, I'm hoping someone can explain to me why the I am not seeing the keys in the buckets that I am expecting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size):

> By default, the terms aggregation will return the buckets for the top ten terms ordered by the doc_count. One can change this default behaviour by setting the size parameter.

So, you need to specify a `"size"` of a number larger than 10 to see more buckets. Or set to `0` to see all the buckets. From the same documentation:

> If set to 0, the size will be set to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

```
   "aggs" : {
        "objects" : {
            "terms" : {
              "field" : "action",
              "size": 0
            }
        }
    }
```